# python: how can I make this code with regular expression?

Tags: python, regex, date

If I input `"1995y 05m 05d"`, then I want to make a program that prints `"950505"`. More example: `"1949y 05m 23d"` --> `"490523"`.

```
import re
Birthday = str(input("insert your birth<(ex) xxxxy **m 00d> : "))
p= re.sub('[ymd ]','',Birthday)
print(p) #result is "xxxx**00"
```

here is my code. How do I fix it? any solutions?

Comment: Any reason to use a regex and not `datetime.strptime` which'll also end up validating you've got a valid date and not just a pattern that looks like it could be one etc... Then format that to %y%m%d ? (but a quick fix is to just ignore the first two characters...)

Comment: As every person older than 18 years should be able to tell you: don't process or store dates with a two digit year.

Comment: @KlausD. but it saves a whole two bytes of storage - what could possibly go wrong? :p

Comment: Also... what's supposed to happen if someone just enters "this doesn't match the format asked for" or "92834927349827492387492837237"? Or... almost the right format but wrong order... eg: "23d 1949y 05m" ?

Comment: Why would you ask someone to enter their bd in such unusual format?

Comment: @JonClements Let us postpone the discussion for 19 years 4 months and 4 days. ;)

Comment: @KlausD. thanks... that should just about give me enough time to find something to occupy all those 2 bytes I'd have saved over the years! :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're basically working with date strings, you can use [`datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to parse them:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> birthday = '1995y 05m 05d'
>>> datetime.strptime(birthday, '%Yy %mm %dd').strftime('%y%m%d')
'950505'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your existing code prints the full year, where you want only two digits. Just skip the first two digits on print.

```
print(p[2:])
```

That will print `p` starting from position 2 (the third character, since lists are counted from 0), with no end to the range, so it prints the entire string except the first two characters (`19` in your sample).

Comment: Better to do `p[-2:]` in case the year already only has two digits.

Comment: @kindall Did you mean `p[-6:]`?

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex expression :

```
>>> import re
>>> a = re.findall("\d+","1995y 05m 05d")
>>> a[0] = a[0][2:]
>>> output = ""
>>> for item in a:
    output += item

>>> int(output)
950505
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Requested regex solution:

```
import re

s = '1995y 05m 05d'
print(''.join(re.findall(r'\d{2}(?=[ymd])', s)))

# 950505
```

Uses `findall` to find all two digits before `y`, `m` and `d` and `join` to join all to required format.

Answer (score 0):

```
birthday = input("birthday").split()
a = ''.join([''.join([i for i in c if i.isdigit()][-2:]) for c in birthday])
```

this does it with out any libraries